# Problem in the printing order of arguments with the python function print()

Tags: python

**I'm trying to print a line with multiple arguments in python but somehow one specific argument prints before all the others:**

```
star = "*"

def how_many_stars(who):
    for i in range(int(len(who))):
         print(star, end="")


print(" |************** PSEUDO :", player_1.get_name(), how_many_stars(player_1.get_name()),"|")
```

The argument that prints before is the `how_many_stars()`
The program returns this (I'm using PyCharm community):

```
***** |************** PSEUDO : Steve None |
```

(`the player_1.get_name` is Steve)
So we clearly see the 5 stars we wanted but it's not at right position at all !
I already tried to change the order of the arguments but it changes nothing.

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: When a function is called, it first evaluates its arguments.  In this case, the arguments to print includes a call to `how_many_stars(player_1.get_name())`.  This causes the print function within function `how_many_stars` to print out stars first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the string, not print it.

```py
>>> def how_many_stars(who):
...     return star * len(who)
...
>>> print(" |************** PSEUDO :", "David", how_many_stars("Steve"), "|")
|************** PSEUDO : David ***** |
```